# Tensorflow object detection serving

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I'm using tensorflow object detection [api](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection). The problem with this api is that it exports frozen graph for inference. I can't use that graph for serving. So, as a work around I followed the tutorial [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-deploy-an-object-detection-model-with-tensorflow-serving-d6436e65d1d9). But when I'm trying to export the graph I'm getting following error:

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Restoring from
>   checkpoint failed. This is most likely due to a mismatch between the
>   current graph and the graph from the checkpoint. Please ensure that
>   you have not altered the graph expected based on the checkpoint.
>   Original error:
>
> Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [1024,4]
>   rhs shape= [1024,8]
>
> [[node save/Assign_258 (defined at
>   /home/deploy/models/research/object_detection/exporter.py:67)  =
>   Assign[T=DT_FLOAT,
>   _class=["loc:@SecondStageBoxPredictor/BoxEncodingPredictor/weights"], use_locking=true, validate_shape=true,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](SecondStageBoxPredictor/BoxEncodingPredictor/weights,
>   save/RestoreV2/_517)]]     [[{{node save/RestoreV2/_522}} =
>   _SendT=DT_FLOAT, client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0",
>   send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0",
>   send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_527_save/RestoreV2",
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]

The error says there is a mismatch in the graph. A possible cause might be that I'm using pretrained graph for training which might have 4 classification and my model has 8 classification. (hence mismatch of shape). There is a similar issue for deeplab [model](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/5390) and their solution for their 
specific model was to start the training with `--initialize_last_layer=False` and  `--last_layers_contain_logits_only=False` parameters. But tensorflow object detection doesn't have that parameters. So, how should I proceed ? Also, is there any other way of serving tensorflow object detection api ?

My config file looks like this:

```
model {
  faster_rcnn {
    num_classes: 1
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 1000
        width: 1000
        resize_method: AREA
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: "faster_rcnn_inception_v2"
      first_stage_features_stride: 16
    }
    first_stage_anchor_generator {
      grid_anchor_generator {
        height_stride: 16
        width_stride: 16
        scales: 0.25
        scales: 0.5
        scales: 1.0
        scales: 2.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.5
        aspect_ratios: 1.0
        aspect_ratios: 2.0
      }
    }
    first_stage_box_predictor_conv_hyperparams {
      op: CONV
      regularizer {
        l2_regularizer {
          weight: 0.0
        }
      }
      initializer {
        truncated_normal_initializer {
          stddev: 0.00999999977648
        }
      }
    }
    first_stage_nms_score_threshold: 0.0
    first_stage_nms_iou_threshold: 0.699999988079
    first_stage_max_proposals: 300
    first_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    first_stage_objectness_loss_weight: 1.0
    initial_crop_size: 14
    maxpool_kernel_size: 2
    maxpool_stride: 2
    second_stage_box_predictor {
      mask_rcnn_box_predictor {
        fc_hyperparams {
          op: FC
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.0
            }
          }
          initializer {
            variance_scaling_initializer {
              factor: 1.0
              uniform: true
              mode: FAN_AVG
            }
          }
        }
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 1.0
      }
    }
    second_stage_post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 0.0
        iou_threshold: 0.600000023842
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 300
      }
      score_converter: SOFTMAX
    }
    second_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    second_stage_classification_loss_weight: 1.0
  }
}
train_config {
  batch_size: 8
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  optimizer {
    adam_optimizer {
      learning_rate {
        manual_step_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.00010000000475
          schedule {
            step: 40000
            learning_rate: 3.00000010611e-05
          }
        }
      }
    }
    use_moving_average: true
  }
  gradient_clipping_by_norm: 10.0
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "/home/deploy/models/research/object_detection/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28/model.ckpt"
  from_detection_checkpoint: true
  num_steps: 60000
  max_number_of_boxes: 100
}
train_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "/home/deploy/models/research/object_detection/Training_carrot_060219/carrot_identify.pbtxt"
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/home/deploy/models/research/object_detection/Training_carrot_060219/train.record"
  }
}
eval_config {
  num_visualizations: 100
  num_examples: 135
  eval_interval_secs: 60
  use_moving_averages: false
}
eval_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "/home/deploy/models/research/object_detection/Training_carrot_060219/carrot_identify.pbtxt"
  shuffle: true
  num_epochs: 1
  num_readers: 1
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/home/deploy/models/research/object_detection/Training_carrot_060219/test.record"
  }
  sample_1_of_n_examples: 1
}
```

Comment: The pretrained model contains `saved_model`, that is used for tf serving.

Comment: @danyfang After training pretrained model in I'm getting empty `saved_model/variables` directory. Is that normal ?

Comment: No, in that case. You will have to generate it yourself.

Comment: @danyfang that's what I'm trying to do by using new `exporter.py` file as given in the link above. But it is giving me above error.

Comment: Yes, I understand the problem now.  When you try the new `exporter.py`, you should use the same config file as provided together with the checkpoint file. (with file paths correctly configured). You should not change any other configs especially `num_classes`.

Comment: @danyfang If I don't change the config file, how would I train on my custom dataset? ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192667/discussion-between-danyfang-and-ansh-kumar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When exporting models for tf serving, the config file and checkpoint files should correspond to each other.

The problem is when exporting the custom trained model, you were using the old config file with new checkpoint files.